# Django Rest Framework: allow Patch, but not Put

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I want to allow `PATCH`ing my model instances, but not `PUT`ting them, and I want to allow updating certain fields only. I am using Django-rest-framework, and I am using `ViewSet`s. If I inherit from the `UpdateModelMixin`, I inevitably get both the `PATCH` and `PUT`.

I know I can write my own `partial_update` implementation, however, I would prefer using a more idiomatic way if there is any. So in short, my question is:

Is there a way to allow `PATCH` method, but not `PUT`?

Is there a way to limit the range of fields allowed for updating in the `PATCH` method without writing a dedicated "input" serializer?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can override viewset's [`http_method_names`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/class-based-views/base/#django.views.generic.base.View.http_method_names) attribute:

```
class MyViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    http_method_names = ['get', 'post', 'patch', 'delete']
```